# Can I safely resize the boot partition?

Tags: boot, 16.04, boot-partition

After installing Ubuntu 16.04, the install procedure laid out my hard drive with the following partitions:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda2           237M  168M   57M  75% /boot
/dev/sda1           511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
...
```

Since then, I now frequently run into the problem that there is not enough space on `/boot` for kernel updates that the automatic software updater wants to install.

I know how to uninstall old kernels; that is not the problem. The problem is that I now have to do it this often. I cannot recall ever experiencing this before in my many years running Ubuntu. Could it be that it is a mistake in the partition lay-out and that Ubuntu perhaps originally intended some of the image files to be installed in `/boot/efi` instead which seems to stay almost unused despite its larger size?

Can I safely shrink the `/boot/efi` partition and enlarge the `/boot` partition to make more room for kernel updates so that I don't have to clean out so often?

Comment: You might have to reinstall Ubuntu for that- remember, choose your mb's wisely.

Comment: the best way is reinstall system. but may be you can try use 'resize2fs' command,  backup your data first!

Comment: @Edity-deleted- I just chose to let the Ubuntu installer partition the hard drive automatically, trusting it would make a sane choice, but apparently it didn't.

Answer (score 4):

**Please,please backup your data if you choose to do this, i don't hold any liability for your data damage.**

You will need.

-A Live USB/CD-drive to boot up with.

Lets begin!

1. Use Ubuntu on Try Ubuntu without Installing option.
2. Gparted should be present, if not use `sudo apt-get install gparted`
3. Hunt down your partition. Yeah I'm not a ubuntu expert, so it might be dev/sda1.
4. RClick on your drive and choose resize/move
5. *insert elevator music here* drag how much you need,
6. click ok (or resize/move)

Now since the changes won't take immediently to use, you need to hit the tick  button to confirm the changes.

Now you can have a great day knowing your computer has been extended.. **:D**